# Как передать запрос со значением параметра null

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть у меня функция

```
SqlCommand GetCommand(string value)
{
    var comm = new SqlCommand();
    comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE anyField = @param";
    comm.Parameters.Add("@param").Value = value;
    ****
}
```

А как быть со случаями, когда value передается null? Ведь язык TSQL не есть фильтр вида `anyField = null`. Неужели переписывать на этот случай заново весь запрос, исправляя на `anyField is null`? Просто параметров на самом деле много, и каждому предусматривать значение null как-то не по христиански.

**UPD:**

Я сделал так... Еще не тестировал, но посмотрите, не чересчур ли это?

```
if (filters != null)
{
    var pCounter = 0;
    filtersPart = $" WHERE ({string.Join(" OR ", filters.Select(d => $"({string.Join(" AND ", d.Select(kv => kv.Value.Value != null ? (kv.Value.Key ? $"[{kv.Key}] = @param{++pCounter}" : $"[{kv.Key}] LIKE @param{++pCounter}") : $"[{kv.Key}] is null"))})"))}) ";
    pCounter = 0;
    foreach(var d in filters)
        foreach(var kv in d)
            if (kv.Value.Value != null)
                res.Parameters.AddWithValue($"param{++pCounter}", kv.Value.Value);
}
```

`filters` тут это `List<Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<bool, object>>>`, где List - это список фильтров через OR, dictionary - это список фильтров через AND, где string - это имя столбца, KeyValuePair - это значение столбца и булейное значение, указывающее, четкое ли нужно совпадение (= @param) или похожее (LIKE @param)

Comment: что нибудь типа `(@param is null and anyField is null) or anyField=@param`. ну возможно привязать дважды придется

Comment: @Mike, а есть другие варианты? Мне не всегда нужно учитывать значения null

Comment: @Mike ой чет я не понял... Прочитайте такой фильтр по русски пожалуйста, не могу врубиться

Comment: да как то больше не приходит в голову. ну еще Coalesce с заменой на какое нибудь не встречающееся значение и передача param с этим значением вместо null. Но это как минимум гарантированный отказ от работы по индексам.

Comment: Если @param NULL то ищем anyField NULL, Иначе ищем anyField=@param. Не дословно, но итоговый логический смысл таков. только если другие условия в запросе еще есть, не забудьте все это вместе в скобки взять, что бы эти `or` бед не натворили :)

Comment: _"как быть со случаями, когда value передается null?"_  -- DBNull.Value

Comment: @Mike, посмотрите UPD в вопросе

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
SqlCommand GetCommand(string value)
{
    var comm = new SqlCommand();
    comm.CommandText = @"
            SELECT *
            FROM MyTable
            WHERE
                    (anyField = @param or anyField is NULL and @param is NULL)
                    -- and/or (другие условия)";
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", (object)value ?? DBNull.Value);
    ...
}
```

Можно

```
comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ISNULL(anyField, '') = ISNULL(@param, '')";
```

но это хуже в плане возможного использования индексов, т.к. будет потеряно [*sargability*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

Либо действительно динамический запрос. Если `value != null` то запрос один:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE anyField = @param
```

а если `value == null`, то другой:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE anyField is NULL
```

Да, может быть сложнее в построении (когда много параметров), но может оказаться выгоднее для исполнения.

Comment: Посмотрите UPD в вопросе и скажите, имеет ли право на жизнь такое решение? )

Comment: @iRumba, т.е. вы множество критериев объединяете в сложное условие `WHERE`? Да вполне имеет право на жизнь (такое практикуется).